# iOS app UI freeze

Tags: ios

There is a strange issue in my app. Sometime when I perform a push action in a navigation controller it will lead to a UI freeze. After that everything with animation goes wrong.

1. push pop animation maybe just effects navigation bar without view content
2. UIView animation stops
3. can't perform new animation

But, if I turn app into background and then foreground, things goes right.

1. view content appears
2. animation continues
3. new animation appears

unfortunately everything will go wrong in next action.

In short, UI seems freezed but it keep alive in real and I can do actions with it. After resign and reactive all actions go right.

It's very strange and I have no more words to describe it. I don't know what and why It happen, even I don't know when it will happen.

Who can tell me what should I do thanks!

Comment: You may be doing some long (database/web interaction)operation on main thread.

Comment: can u post some code as to after which the UI Freezes?

Comment: What language are you writing in? Are you using storyboards to push a new controller? Are you doing anything strange with pushing the controllers? Two things you should check first as they are best candidates to produce your result: 1st check if you are calling the push on main thread (you should). 2nd check the push is called only once as sequential calls may produce issues.

Comment: I'm sure that every action is executed on main thread, otherwise more strange things will happen :)     Not only push, pop but also other animations are wrong.

Comment: I have noticed this bug as well! After updating from Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2 to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.1 our app sometimes (very rarely) freezes, but it doesn't crash. The input/touch screen becomes totally unresponsive. If I minimize the app (pressing Home button) and then going back to the app the UI sometimes becomes responsive just to sometimes become unresponsive again (with no clear pattern to reproduce it). Force quitting the app makes the app work again.

Comment: glad to hear that I'm not the only one...  do you have any idea to fix or make it better?

Comment: all my problems appear in a view controller which is presented from bottom, most of them appear when I perform a push action after a view animation. do you have any same or special behavior may lead to wrong?

Comment: I don't think we have experienced this in some weeks time now. Have you? Not sure if this was at all related to IOS 9.0 if so maybe it was fixed in 9.1 or 9.2. But I have a vague memory that we experienced this bug in 8.4 as well. But built under Xcode 7. So maybe it was an Xcode bug fixed in 7.1 or 7.2? :S

Comment: unfortunately it remains :(   But I'm sure that it caused by hidding navigation bar. pop from or to a view controller which has hidden it's navigation bar by panning on the left edge, you can easily run into problem, maybe. Now I have two ways to avoid that issue, disabling the pan gesture or not using push or pop.

Comment: for more details, it will make all view controllers in same navigation controller wrong. for example, navigation.A present navigation.B, if the problem appears in navigation.B, all wrongs happen in B, everything is fine in A.

Comment: @debuggenius do you have any updates on this?

Comment: @manmal finally I removed all push/pop actions from view controllers with hidden navigation bar and no more crash found.  Till now I don't know what exactly happened :(

Comment: @debuggenius thank you! that's a very good hint.